# http call out to an external REST webservice

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, namedcredentials, httpcalloutmock

**Simple use case -**
make a http call out to an external REST webservice. Parse the JSON response.

I know I could do this using Flow, but due to the business requirement have opted for Apex Class.

Can someone please tell me if I have I captured all of the steps ?

1. Configure Remote Site Setting
2. Configure the Named Credential and  External Credentials
3. Create Permission Set, did the step of adding the External Credentials Principal access
4. Create Apex Classes and Text Classes

Am i missing something ?

Futher, If the endpoint URL is not yet available, what is the optimal approach to organize a shell based on above steps? Then, when the endpoint url and creds become avaiable, use the Shell for effective implementation.

Comment: As a rule, if you have a named credential, you don't need a Remote Site Setting - the Named Credential acts as the safe listing

Comment: also, user needs View on UserExternalCredential object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One step which you have missed is adding apex class permissions for permission set you created.

If you know the request and response, but api is still under development, use postman(or any mock api) to create a mock server which serves you with the required responses. This will help you to develop and confirm your classes easily.
Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks! That's super helpful.